# Is there a list of commands for keyboard shortcuts in Xfce 4?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut, xfce

I am relatively new to Xfce, but I love it. I am now looking into keyboard shortcuts and I am having problems with finding the right syntax for commands to bind keyboard shortcuts to.

I see two ways to set keyboard shortcuts:

1. menu → *Settings* → *Keyboard* → tab *Application Shortcuts*
2. file `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml\xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`

The settings from option 1 I see in a `<property name="custom">` section of option 2. But the file contains another `<property name="custom">` that I don't see in the *Keyboard Settings* dialog, with commands like `cycle_window_key`, `close_window_key`, etc.

I would like to add keyboard shortcuts like tiling a window to the left, top, right, or bottom of the screen, but I can't find a list of commands and I have searched for a long time now.

I cannot seem to use `move_window_up_key` as a command, so I would love to see a list of `*_key` definitions as well.

Do these lists exist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although not a complete list (haven't been able to find a comprehensive one myself), take a peek at your window manager settings instead:

Menu → *Settings* → *Window Manager* → *Keyboard*

[image: Xfce 4 Window Manager]

Comment: Thanks, that does help a lot. I was so focused on the Keyboard dialog I forgot these were shortcuts for the Window Manager that has its own dialog!

Comment: I didn't realize that Window Manager and Keyboard shortcut settings are entirely different!!! Until now.

Answer (score 1):

> haven't been able to find a comprehensive one myself

Neither have I, but it looks like Xfce uses the common method of invoking the command using the name of the associated binary. On my system there are a bunch of them in *usr/bin/* I found the location by using locate to find a typical command with

```
locate xfce4-terminal
```

It looks like they have man pages so, for example, you can find out about the usage of the Xfce 4 terminal with the command

```
man xfce4-terminal
```

You you are not limited to binding only Xfce commands to keystrokes, and can start any program using the same command you would use in a terminal.